# how to convert Cassandra Map to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to read the data from cassandra column family of type `map<string, int>` and want to convert it to Pandas dataframe. Which further i want to use to train the model in python as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) in  classification of iris species.

If, i would have used the csv to train the model. Then it would have looked like this:

```
label,  f1, f2, f3, f4, f5
  0  ,  11 , 1, 6 , 1,  2  
  1  ,  5,   5, 1 , 2,  6
  0  ,  12,  9, 3 , 6,  8
  0  ,  9,  3,  8,  1,  0
```

Cassandra column family :

```
                  FeatureSet                    |   label

{'f1': 11, 'f2': 1, 'f3': 6, 'f4': 1, 'f5': 2}  |     0
{'f1': 5, 'f2':  5, 'f3': 1, 'f4': 2, 'f5': 6}  |     1
{'f1': 12, 'f2': 9, 'f3': 3, 'f4': 6, 'f5': 8}  |     0
{'f1': 9, 'f2': 3, 'f3': 8, 'f4': 1, 'f5': 0}   |     0
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn2pmml import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

CASSANDRA_HOST = ['172.16.X.Y','172.16.X1.Y1'] 
CASSANDRA_PORT = 9042
CASSANDRA_DB = "KEYSPACE"
CASSANDRA_TABLE = "COLUMNFAMILY"

cluster = Cluster(contact_points=CASSANDRA_HOST, port=CASSANDRA_PORT)
session = cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_DB)

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM {}.{};".format(CASSANDRA_DB, CASSANDRA_TABLE)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for row in session.execute(sql_query):  
            What should i write here and get X_train, Y_train in pandas dataframe 



iris_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
    ("classifier", DecisionTreeClassifier())
])
iris_pipeline.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484806/5741205):

```
import pandas as pd
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

def pandas_factory(colnames, rows):
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)

CASSANDRA_HOST = ['172.16.X.Y','172.16.X1.Y1'] 
CASSANDRA_PORT = 9042
CASSANDRA_DB = "KEYSPACE"
CASSANDRA_TABLE = "COLUMNFAMILY"

cluster = Cluster(contact_points=CASSANDRA_HOST, port=CASSANDRA_PORT)
session = cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_DB)

session.row_factory = pandas_factory
session.default_fetch_size = None

query = "SELECT * FROM {}.{};".format(CASSANDRA_DB, CASSANDRA_TABLE)

rslt = session.execute(query, timeout=None)
df = rslt._current_rows
```

Comment: I already tried this method. But `print df` only the keys of map in the output i.e. (f1, f2, f3, f4). Where as when i print `df.values` it gives `[OrderedMapSerializedKey([(u'f1', 11), (u'f2', 1), (u'f3', 6), (u'f4', 1), (u'f5', 2)])]`. I cannot train it using these values. It should return me the numeric values along with headers in the first row. Just like I mentioned in the csv

Answer (score 1):

I posted a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036607/transforming-a-cassandra-orderedmapserializedkey-to-a-python-dictionary/46101924#46101924) for the same question to read `OrderedMapSerializedKey` Cassandra map field as a dict into your dataframe.

---

**EDIT:**

In previous solution I replaced only the first (0th) row of Cassandra dataset (`rows` are list of tuples where every tuple is a row in Cassandra)

```
from cassandra.util import OrderedMapSerializedKey

def pandas_factory(colnames, rows):

    # Convert tuple items of 'rows' into list (elements of tuples cannot be replaced)
    rows = [list(i) for i in rows]

    # Convert only 'OrderedMapSerializedKey' type list elements into dict
    for idx_row, i_row in enumerate(rows):

        for idx_value, i_value in enumerate(i_row):

            if type(i_value) is OrderedMapSerializedKey:

                rows[idx_row][idx_value] = dict(rows[idx_row][idx_value])

    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MaxU answer, if you want to see your result as data frame all you need to do is to add one more line:

df = pd.DataFrame(rslt._current_rows)