# Get dict instead of OrderedMapSerializedKey when reading Cassandra with Python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am trying to read a row from a Cassandra table in Python. This table has a `map<text, some_object>` field where `some_object` is a user defined type. This type then further has a `map<text, text>` for example in it, etc...

The problem is, when I read a row from such a table, every map field is read into a OrderedMapSerializedKey type object, and I need it to be a dict for proper JSON serialization afterwards.

Can I somehow tell the Python driver for Cassandra to read it as dict in the first place? If not, what would be an alternative solution? I know I can transform the OrderedMapSerializedKey field to dict myself (as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036607/transforming-a-cassandra-orderedmapserializedkey-to-a-python-dictionary)), but as I mentioned, the whole row can be a complicated nested structure with many maps within, so this is not a viable solution.